# List initialization of std::map with a struct as a key

Tags: c++, stdmap

I currently have this:

```
struct Foo {
    int value = 12;
    Foo(int a) : value(a) {}
};
```

and I am trying to do this:

```
std::map<Foo,int> m{
    {{1}, 2}
};
```

Why is the above giving the compile error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Foo' and 'const Foo')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile the code you provided with `g++`, I get a *different* (and self-explanatory) error:

```
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Foo]’:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_function.h:408:20: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Foo’ and ‘const Foo’)
```

Since you are using `Foo` as the key in a sorted container, you must tell the compiler how to compare one `Foo` to another.

For example, adding this method makes it compile:

```
bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
  return lhs.value < rhs.value;
}
```

Or, if you are using C++20, you can simply add a [defaulted three-way comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons#Defaulted_three-way_comparison) to the `struct` to define all comparison operators:

```cpp
friend auto operator<=>(const Foo&, const Foo&) = default;
```